# I can't connect to bitbucket, not through ssh not through https

Tags: git, connection

Like in the subject. When I type `git push origin master` console freezes and there is no response. When I try to connect by https its the same error connection timeout. Can you load that website https://bitbucket.org/ ?

Comment: Sure I can. There are tools on the internet that can load address for you to check that. Looks like something is misconfigured on your side. I use bitbucket everyday.

Comment: its just happen, everyting worked and just suddenly this.

Comment: Network issues perhaps. I usually have a remote host which I can log in via ssh, and try things from there.

Comment: I founded solution

Comment: Good. Share with people, and mark this as done.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was something with dns. when i `ping http://bitbucket.org` i got response unknown host.

to fix this

`sudo nano /etc/hosts`

and add for example(google dns)

`8.8.8.8    http://bitbucket.org`